# How can I resolve a promise without moving forward in the code

Tags: reactjs, promise, functional-programming, react-redux

I have a line of a code that returns a promise and I want the code to wait till I get an result. I have tried async and await like in .NET but I am new to functional programming

```
 var customer= storeData.customers.CustomerState.layoutCustomer.getCustomer()  // This returns a promise
```

How can I stop the code till the promise is resolved and customer variable has data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
.then((e) => {
    //code here
})
```

Because the `.then()` function makes it wait till completed

Answer (score 2):

You have to put this to any async function and use await on this call. Something like this:

```
async function asyncCall() {
     const customer = await storeData.customers.CustomerState.layoutCustomer.getCustomer();
     console.log(customer); // Here is the result
}
```